# Add additional quality of service channel modes to NetworkManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I need to add a few additional quality of service channel modes to NetworkManager and I'm attempting to do it in this way:

```
NetworkManager netMan;

void Start () {
ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);
cc.PacketSize = 1440;

netMan.connectionConfig = cc;
}
```

But I'm getting the error : `Property or indexer 'NetworkManager.connectionConfig' cannot be assigned to -- it is readonly`

If the property is read-only then what is the proper way to create additional channels to NetworkManager?

...full function below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour {

    public Texture2D textureToSend;
    string messageToSend = "Test Message";

    NetworkManager netMan;

    private int reliableChannel;
    private int reliableSeqChannel;
    private int reliableFragChannel;
    private int unreliableChannel;
    private int unreliableSeqChannel;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        ConnectionConfig cc = new ConnectionConfig();

        reliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
        reliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
        reliableFragChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
        unreliableChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
        unreliableSeqChannel = cc.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);
        cc.PacketSize = 1440;

        netMan.connectionConfig = cc;

        NetworkManager.singleton.StartHost();
        Debug.Log("Server Started.");
    }

    public void SendOnButtonPress()
    {
        SendTexture(textureToSend, messageToSend);
    }

    //Call to send the Texture and a simple string message
    public void SendTexture(Texture2D texture, string message)
    {
        TextureMessage msg = new TextureMessage();

        //Convert Texture2D to byte array

        msg.textureBytes = texture.GetRawTextureData();
        msg.message = message;

        NetworkServer.SendToAll(MyMsgType.texture, msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkManager.connectionConfig` is a read-only property because only its `get{}` property is implemented. The `set{}` property is not implemented.

Although, you can add more channes with:

```
NetworkManager.connectionConfig.AddChannel(QosType).
```

In your case:

```
NetworkManager netMan;

void Start()
{
    netMan.connectionConfig.AddChannel(QosType.Reliable);
    netMan.connectionConfig.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableSequenced);
    netMan.connectionConfig.AddChannel(QosType.ReliableFragmented);
    netMan.connectionConfig.AddChannel(QosType.Unreliable);
    netMan.connectionConfig.AddChannel(QosType.UnreliableSequenced);
}
```

Note that `netMan` is not initialized yet. You must do that with the `GetComponent` or `AddComponent` function before using the code in the `Start` function above or you will get a run-time error.